# Ramp generator using 555 timer

Tags: 555

I want to use a 555 timer to generate a ramp to my soft starter. The problem is, I want it to be continuous after reaching it's value. Unlike this shown below,

[image]

Instead of discharging I want it to remain on. How can I adjust this basic 555 ramp generator circuit to do this?

Comment: Why is using a 555 a design requirement?

Comment: It's not necessarily a requirement, I figured it would be the easiest to work with. However I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Did you think about a non inverting integrator? You will need a rail to rail single supply op amp, a couple of resistors and a capacitor. Is the ramp duration time-critical? What are the initial and final voltages? How much current do you need?

Comment: My voltage and current specs aren't really finalized yet. I want my ramp duration to be about 2 seconds but to have the ability to be adjusted up to 5 seconds using a pot.

Comment: Tell us what you really want to accomplish, not how you think it should be done.  A 555 timer for this seems both inappropriate and silly in the first place, but without knowing what you actually want, it is not possible to suggest a alternative.

Comment: Then a non inverting integrator should do the trick. You can adjust the timing with a potentiometer too.

Comment: @OlinLathrop If it's not possible to suggest an alternative, how come Vladimir did? You can't just say that what I think is inappropriate and silly and not back it up. Post something productive or don't comment at all. 

Vladimir thank-you I will turn my focus onto the non-inverting integrator rather than the 555 timer.

Comment: Vladimir is guessing.  It's incredible that you spent the effort arguing instead of fixing the problem.  Since you won't coorperate, this is a non-question and needs to be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disconnect pin 6 (threshold) from the output and pull it to ground with a resistor.
You can still pull it to supply voltage to manually reset the output.

Note that the output will go to the full supply voltage instead of 2/3 of it as in the given circuit.

Comment: It answers your question, but an OpAmp as integrator is probably better. Maybe even a simple RC suffices.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on that please? I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: RC = resistor capacitor.